# Raspberry Pi 2, how to disable device_tree to enable SPI?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, spi, device-tree

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, Model B, and I'd like to use the SPI to talk to another Pi (for later using it for more SPI-devices). I'd also like to use [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) for C-coding my program.

I thought I would ensure I had everything I needed, so i ran a full upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

I installed`WiringPi`, and enabling SPI to be loaded from `raspi-config`, but I still can't do a `gpio load SPI` without the following error:

```
gpio: Unable to load/unload modules as this Pi has the device tree enabled.
  You need to run the raspi-config program (as root) and select the
  modules (SPI or I2C) that you wish to load/unload there and reboot.
  There is more information here:
    https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=97314
```

I then tried what [the link suggested](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=97314):

> ... add "device_tree=" to your config.txt and reboot.

```
$ nano sudo /boot/config.txt
# Go to last line
# Add 'device_tree='
# Save, and exit
$ sudo reboot
```

Then I tried `gpio load spi`, but I still get the same error.

SPI is enabled in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
$ cat /boot/config.txt | grep spi
dtparam=spi=on
```

Have any of you suggestions to, what I can try to enable my SPI?

Comment: *"I'd like to use the SPI to talk to another Pi"* -- Probably a bad idea. (1) Electrically SPI is intended for short-distance chip to chip communication on the same board, and not intended for board to board communication.  That's not to say it has never been done.  Just don't expect reliable megabits-per-sec transfer rates on the cheap.  (2) Linux (at least up to version 4.6) doesn't support SPI slave mode.  So you will have to find or write a device driver to operate one of the the SPI controllers in slave mode.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to put some simple hardware in the middle so you can operate both ends in SPI master mode. There seem to be SPI-to-UART modules available that could do the trick.

Comment: OP, did you get your problem resolved? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @drs-david-soft - no, no solution :(

Comment: @RasmusBækgaard Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, @Mr.Branch

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/spi-enabled-in-device-tree-but-i-cant-use-it),`gpio load spi` is deprecated.